# Android Studio 1.4 RC1 Unknown command-line option '-X'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded Android version 1.4 RC 1

When i try to do a gadle sync it falis with the following error.

Im not able to figure out the problem.

Please find below

Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unknown command-line option '-X'.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be because you have specified any command line option in android studio settings. You can check this by going to

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

and see "Command-line-options" and check if anything is give. (In your case -x). If so remove it and click Apply and Ok. Now restart your android studio and try building